# Python -Spawn a methode from a class

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm completly new in python, i'm looking for "**thread**" a methode from a **class**.
unfortunately, its seem dificult to understand.

So :
I have a class with methode :

```
First methode named "readLog" : will read a log file, and return true if it found a specific string (txt)
Second methode named "checkLog" : will check if there is a new one log file, (txt)
```

I dont know how :

**Run this 2 methode in paralelle:**

And if readLog **found a specific string**, call another methode

and in "checkLog" **found a new log file**, will **stop** "readlog" process, and **start** a new one file the new "log path" ( passed in parametre )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `threading` module to get the similar response

```
import threading
import os
import time

class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.continue_reading = True


    def readLog(self, logpath, searchstring):
        with open(logpath, "r") as f:
            data = f.readlines()

        for line in data:
            if self.continue_reading:
                if searchstring in line:
                    # Other method here
                    return line
            else:
                return None

    def checkLog(self, new_filename, directory, searchstring):
        # If new file is found
        if new_filename in os.listdir(directory):
            self.continue_reading = False
            # Wait for some time to let the readlog be finished
            time.sleep(1)
            self.continue_reading = True
            th = threading.Thread(
                target=self.readLog,
                args=(os.path.join(directory, new_filename), searchstring)
            )
            th.start()
```

When you call checkLog method, it will spawn new threads for new files, and it will close them as soon as a new-er file is detected.